# Google recaptcha one page on ASP (Classic)

Tags: php, asp.net, recaptcha

I'm working in ASP right now. I love coding using PHP but my company use ASP to their website. On my company website there is form that connected to our CRM, regarding to many Spam issued we need to put Google recaptcha to the form.

Below is PHP code for recaptcha that I used for many website that I developed, It is possible to have same method like this code on ASP? I just need only one page only.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha- response'])):
    //your site secret key
    $secret = '6Le5ohYUAAAAAAWeXQ4TnEMsOrW7wSw4WcNUVyS7';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    if($responseData->success):         
        $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    endif;
else:
$errMsg = '';
$succMsg = '';
endif;
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Google reCAPTCHA</title>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="registration">
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
    <?php if(!empty($errMsg)): ?><div class="errMsg"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($succMsg)): ?><div class="succMsg"><?php echo $succMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="form-info">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:''; ?>" placeholder="Your full name" name="name" >
            <input type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:''; ?>" placeholder="Email adress" name="email" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Message..." name="message"><?php echo !empty($message)?$message:''; ?></textarea>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le5ohYUAAAAAPDz2w2tDQ-3AgYwgEQmkOhnwYhO"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
    </div>          
    <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Google recaotcha with Clasic ASP. You can see their documenttaion here
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/asp